# Import mixin and config while working with css module

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-modules

In my react app I'm trying to implement CSS modules to my project.

Here's my `App.sass` :

```
/*entry point for global styles*/


/*Include config files*/

@import "./style/utils/config"
@import "./style/utils/mixin"


// Font Icon

@import "./style/ionicons"
```

I just want to use my mixin in my css module as well.

`Header.module.sass`

```
@import "../../App"
.header
  color: red
  background: #000
  .site-name
    a
      @include link
```

is there anyway to use mixin globally without using `@import "../../App"` on every css module file ?

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution by any chance? I'm using create react app.

Comment: no tbh,I ended up importing mixin or any other global files on everywhere i need them